# How would i go about retopology for this object?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I am a blender newbie and have modeled and sculpted this tombstone with a cool symbol and some cracks on it but somewhere along the line it made the whole mesh made of tris...

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming that this is a problem for retopology so, how do I fix it and then how should I do the retopology? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest method I like to use is a remesh modifier and a decimate modifier. Works nice and fast. This tutorial might also help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUzJefYNQlI

Comment: If anything needs clearing up tell me :)

Comment: I have applied the remesh modifier and it just deformed my mesh. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello are you still online?

Comment: I sure am, got a problem?

Comment: yes the remesh modifier just distorted my mesh instead of getting rid of the tris?

Comment: Hello Are you Still there I have posted the question.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the remesh modifier is just distorting my mesh :(

Comment: Hello you there? the remesh modified is distorting my mesh.

Comment: Yes, it will do that. You can try out a corrective smooth modifier or a decimate modifier after it. Or you can try not using a remesh, and only using a decimate modifier.

Comment: ok will try when I get on my pc later.I have been considering purchasing a online course,would you reccomend it for a beginner like me?

Comment: I 100% recommend courses. Look on the Blender Market and Udemy for cool Blender courses (go to Udemy first, imo). Udemy has tons of awesome courses for absolute dirt-cheap. Just a heads up, it says the courses are on sale. They are on sale like 99% of the time, usually courses are about 10-30 USD, even if it says the normal price is 200 USD.

Answer (score 0):

you can add plane (a separate object from your high poly not together with it) and then add a shrinkwrap modifier select the target to your high poly mesg , and then start shaping it like you high poly mesh and when you have finished apply the modifier.

Comment: @ClashWithX also you can use this addon https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow

Comment: I don't spend any money on this sort of stuff :( is there a tutorial for the other option floating around the internet somewhere?

Comment: @ClashWithX its for free -_- just click clone download

Comment: It says purchase on the blender market?

Comment: Oh sorry I was in mobile thx mate